# In RxJS, how to prevent operators from emitting values if the source observable hasn't emitted any?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have three observables `foo$`, `bar$` and `baz$` that I merge together to form another observable. This is working as expected:

- The stream starts with `>>>`
- Each value are emitted one by one
- The stream ends with `<<<`

```js
const foo$ = of('foo');
const bar$ = of('bar');
const baz$ = of('baz');

merge(foo$, bar$, baz$).pipe(startWith('>>>'), endWith('<<<')).subscribe(str => {
  console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>const {merge, of} = rxjs; const {startWith, endWith} = rxjs.operators;</script>
```

Now if none of the three observables above emit a value, I do not want to output neither `>>>` nor `<<<`. So `startWith` and `endWith` can only "run" if `merge(foo$, bar$, baz$)` actually emits a value.

In order to simulate that I'm rejecting all values emitted by `foo$`, `bar$` and `baz$` with a filtering function.

```js
const foo$ = of('foo').pipe(filter(() => false));
const bar$ = of('bar').pipe(filter(() => false));
const baz$ = of('baz').pipe(filter(() => false));

merge(foo$, bar$, baz$).pipe(startWith('>>>'), endWith('<<<')).subscribe(str => {
  console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>const {merge, of} = rxjs; const {startWith, endWith, filter} = rxjs.operators</script>
```

However as you can see in the output, both `startWith` and `endWith` have emitted their value even though the `merge()` hasn't produced any.

**Question**: How can I prevent `startWith` and `endWith` from executing if the observable did not emit a single value?

Answer (score 3):

The first condition is simple. You can just prepend the first emission with `concatMap`:

```
mergeMap((v, index) => index === 0 ? of('>>>', v) : of(v))
```

The second condition is more tricky. You want basically the right opposite to `defaultIfEmpty`. I can't think of any simple solution so I'd probably use `endWith` anyway and just ignore the emission if it's the first and only emission (which means the source just completed without emitting anything):

```
endWith('<<<'),
filter((v, index) => index !== 0 || v !== '<<<'),
```

Complete example:

```
const foo$ = of('foo');//.pipe(filter(() => false));
const bar$ = of('bar');//).pipe(filter(() => false));
const baz$ = of('baz');//.pipe(filter(() => false));

merge(foo$, bar$, baz$).pipe(
  mergeMap((v, index) => index === 0 ? of('>>>', v) : of(v)),
  endWith('<<<'),
  filter((v, index) => index !== 0 || v !== '<<<'),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-n2alkc?file=index.ts

Comment: Thank you for this. I feel the answer from @fridoo is more idiomatic. +1 though

Comment: Just be aware that that solution might produce different results for "hot" Observables where the first emission might be swallowed. I guess you could add the first emission to `startWith` but then it will behave differently for "cold" Observables anyway... so I don't know what is the best solution here. Probably depends on your particular use-case.

Answer (score 3):

You could assign the merged observable to a variable, take the first element from the stream and then map to the observable you want to execute when atleast one value has been emitted.

```ts
const foo$ = of('foo').pipe(filter(() => false))
const bar$ = of('bar').pipe(filter(() => false))
const baz$ = of('baz').pipe(filter(() => false))

const merged$ = merge(foo$, bar$, baz$);
merged$.pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(() => merged$.pipe(
    startWith('>>>'),
    endWith('<<<')
  ))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-phspsc

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That works when `merged$` does not emit at all. Otherwise if one of the merged observable emits a value, neither `startWith` nor `endWith` emit their value.

Comment: @customcommander No, as soon as one of the merged observables emits a value you're switchmapping to the other stream that emits with `startWith` and `endWith`. Please have a look at my stackblitz and remove `.pipe(filter(() => false))` for one of the observables.

Comment: Apologies. I did try it and it didn't work but I must have done a typo somewhere when I rewrote my code from your answer. I copy/pasted your code and it just worked ;) I like this answer a lot. I'll wait for some more answers () before I decide on one. +1 though

Comment: @customcommander, fridoo, this leads to double subscription to the `merged$`. So one will need to [share](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/share/) the source and do a `concat` inside of the `switchMap`.

Comment: @kos My understanding is that `switchMap` will unsubscribe from the source observable. So it should be fine unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @customcommander `switchMap` adds inner observable to outer subscription. So first you subscribe to `merged$` in the main chain, then it is subscribed to as the inner observable of the `switchMap`. See `a.js` here: https://thinkrx.io/gist/070a57d163cae958473b6ee36e9b0798 , explanations in comments. To see how it skips the first emission with hot observables, see `b.js`. Both files have suggestions for fixes. So, know whether your observable is hot or cold. If its cold -- understand if you can make it hot. And apply a proper fix. FYI

Answer (score 2):

I see that all answers are done **combining operators**, but doing this solution with only operators is kind of tricky, why not just **create your own observable**? I think this solution is the **easiest one** to understand. **No hidden cleverness**, no complex operator combinations, no subscription repetitions...

Solution:

```js
const foo$ = of('foo')//.pipe(filter(() => false));
const bar$ = of('bar')//.pipe(filter(() => false));
const baz$ = of('baz')//.pipe(filter(() => false));

function wrapIfOnEmit$(...obs) {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    let hasEmitted;
    const subscription = merge(...obs).subscribe((data) => {
      if (!hasEmitted) {
        observer.next('>>>');
        hasEmitted = true;
      }
      observer.next(data);
    },
    (error) => observer.error(error),
    () => {
      if (hasEmitted) observer.next('<<<');
      observer.complete();
    })
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  })
}

wrapIfOnEmit$(foo$, bar$, baz$).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>const {merge, of, Observable} = rxjs; const {filter} = rxjs.operators</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `startWith`:

> Returns an Observable that emits the items you specify as arguments before it begins to emit items emitted by the source Observable.

So `startWith` and `endWith` will always run.

I dont know what your expected result should be, but if you only want to concatenate the strings for each emitted value you could use the `map` or `switchMap` operators.

EDIT:
Example with `map` to concat each value:

```js
const foo$ = of('foo').pipe(filter(() => false));
const bar$ = of('bar').pipe(filter(() => false));
const baz$ = of('baz').pipe(filter(() => false));

merge(foo$, bar$, baz$).pipe(map(v => `>>>${v}<<<`)).subscribe(str => {
  console.log(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>const {merge, of} = rxjs; const {startWith, endWith, filter, map} = rxjs.operators</script>
```

Comment: My expected output is that if `merge()` does not emit a value then I should not see `>>>` nor `<<<` in the console. Could you fork one of my snippet and show me how to use `switchMap` for example? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I have a stream which may or may not produce value. When the stream completes I need to concatenate the emitted strings and only then apply my prefix/suffix. I could apply my affixes outside of a pipe but I was wondering if that behaviour could be added into it. Hope this clarifies a bit.

Comment: @customcommander Ive added an example, hope thats what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks for this but wouldn't that apply the affixes to every value emitted? I need to emit `>>>` and `<<<` only once. The former at the start of the stream, the latter at the end of the stream.

Comment: I can see the confusion, I have edited my question. Sorry.

Comment: The thing is, observables are streams  So you normally dont know when the "last" value is emitted, because technically there is no last value (I may be wrong). Also in the original docs I cant even find `endWith` so I guess its not officially in ReactiveX.
For startWith you could just check for `i===0` in `map` and then concat else, return the original value.

Comment: @CodeSpirit, You're right: we don't know if the value is last, until we receive a `complete` notification on the stream. And on top of that: we even might never receive a complete notification. Regarding `endWith` — 
 its there: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/endWith (I think, they've added it in one of the the 6th versions, so you might be checking outdated docs, FYI).

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is to use a **[materialize-dematerialize operators](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/dematerialize/)** pair:

```js
source$.pipe(
  // turn all events on stream into Notifications
  materialize(),

  // wrap elements only if they are present
  switchMap((event, index) => {
    // if its first event and its a value
    if (index === 0 && event.kind === 'N') {
      const startingNotification = new Notification('N', '>>>', undefined);
      return of(startingNotification, event);
    }

    // if its a completion event and it not a first event
    if (index > 0 && event.kind === 'C') {
      const endingNotification = new Notification('N', '<<<', undefined);
      return of(endingNotification, event);
    }

    return of(event);
  }),

  // turn Notifications back to events on stream
  dematerialize()
)
```

[image: Wrap source emission only if its not empty]

Play with this code in a playground:
**https://thinkrx.io/gist/5a7a7f1338737e452ff6a1937b5fe05a**
*for convenience, I've added an empty and error source there as well*

Hope this helps

Comment: I think, another way would be to use `throwIfEmpty` with `startWith` and `endWith`, followed by `catchError`, that will suppress "empty error" and pass through original errors. Need to test this approach though. GL